# Invalid use of incomplete type struct, even with forward declaration

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

I'm aware of circular dependencies, but even with forward declarations I get this area.
What am I doing wrong?

```
// facility.h
class Area;

class Facility {
public:
    Facility();
    Area* getAreaThisIn();
    void setAreaThisIsIn(Area* area);
private:
    Area* __area;
};

// facility.cpp
#include "facility.h"
#include "area.h"
{ ... }

// area.h
class Facility;
class Area {
public:
    Area(int ID);
    int getId();

private:
    std::list<Facility*> _facilities;
};

// area.cpp
#include "area.h"
#include "facility.h"
```

So this compiles fine, but if I do

```
// foo.h
#include "facility.h"
class Foo { .. };

// foo.cpp
#include "foo.h"
void Foo::function() {
    Facility* f = new Facility();
    int id = f->getAreaThisIsIn()->getId();
```

When I get `invalid use of incomplete type struct Area`

Comment: Have you included **area.h** in whatever file you are defining `Foo::function()`?

Comment: I've tried compiling this with g++ (adding in stub definitions of the `Facility` and `Area` methods) after correcting the `getAreaThisIn()` typo in `facility.h` (should be `getAreaThisIsIn()`) and it compiled for me.  Though my `Foo.cpp` did include both headers.

Comment: Note that identifiers that start with two underscores (`__area` I'm looking at you) are reserved by the implementation and shouldn't be used.

Comment: Note: I'd edit out the typos but since this post is mostly code it won't let me, unless I rewrite the whole question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For `Facility* f = new Facility();` you need a full declaration, not just forward declaration.

Comment: What do you mean? I thought including in the cpp is good enough?

Comment: @robev Including the `facility.h` should work just fine, unless there are other errors.

Comment: @robev - Things will clear up if you show `Foo` class header and it's source file.

Comment: There, fixed. I thought including facility is good enough to get area..I have to include both?

Comment: Yes, you do.  Including `facility.h` only brings in the forward declaration of `Area`.  But since you're using an `Area` method you need to bring in the full declaration of `Area`.  Which given your setup means you have to include `area.h`.

Comment: @robev If you want area, include area, if you want facility, include facility, it's that simple.

Comment: -1: Error comes up in  int id = f->getAreaThisIsIn()->getId(); Since calling getId() needs to know about Area. So including area.h is necessary here...not for creating an instance of Facility!

Answer (score 25):

To clarify:  a forward declaration allows you to operate on an object if very limited ways:

```
struct Foo; // forward declaration

int bar(Foo* f); // allowed, makes sense in a header file

Foo* baz(); // allowed

Foo* f = new Foo(); // not allowed, as the compiler doesn't
                    // know how big a Foo object is
                    // and therefore can't allocate that much
                    // memory and return a pointer to it

f->quux(); // also not allowed, as the compiler doesn't know
           // what members Foo has
```

Forward declarations can help in some cases.  For instance, if the functions in a header only ever take pointers to objects instead of the objects, then you don't need to `#include` the whole class definition for that header.  This can improve your compile times.  But the implementation for that header is almost guaranteed to need to `#include` the relevant definition because you're likely going to want to allocate those objects, call methods on those objects, etc. and you need more than a forward declaration to do that.

Answer (score 4):

Did you #include both area.h and facility.h in foo.cpp (assuming this is the file where you get the error)?

Comment: Yes, since you are calling member functions for both Area and Facility instances in your code, you have to.