# Problems with forward declaration - Friend functions and line / point classes

Tags: c++, class, forward-declaration

I have a demo program for understanding of friend function. I am stuck up with errors related to forward declaration stuff, I guess.

I have a point class which has x & y co-ordinates. The line class has two objects of point class. Now I have a function in line class which will calculate the slope of the line.

This is my program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class point
{
    int x,y;
public:
    point(int,int);
    point();
    friend float line::slope();
};

point::point(int a, int b)
{
    x=a;
    y=b;
}

point::point()
{
}

class line
{
    point p1,p2;
public:
    line(point,point);
    float slope();
};

line::line(point p1, point p2)
{
    this->p1=p1;
    this->p2=p2;
}

float line::slope()
{
    float s;
    s=((float)p2.y-p1.y)/(p2.x-p1.x);
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    float sl;
    point obj(5,10);
    point obj1(4,8);
    line obj3(obj,obj1);
    sl=obj3.slope();
    cout<<"\n slope:"<<sl;
    return 0;
}
```

It is giving me compiler errors with respect to forward declarations due to the following:

1. When I try to define my line class first, it does not know about the point class. Even if I **forward declare the point class**, that wont suffice coz to create objects of the point class, the compiler should know the size of the point class and hence the whole class itself. Understood it through explanation in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5543788
2. If I define the point class first, it needs to know the friend function slope and hence the class line.
   So I tried to provide the forward declaration for the line class and the slope function like this before defining the point class:

> class line;
>
> ```
> float line::slope();
>
> class point
> {
>     int x,y;
> public:
>     point(int,int);
>     point();
>     friend float line::slope();
> };
> ```

Now this gives me the following errors:

```
friend1.cpp:5: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct line’
friend1.cpp:4: error: forward declaration of ‘struct line’
friend1.cpp:13: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct line’
friend1.cpp:4: error: forward declaration of ‘struct line’
friend1.cpp: In member function ‘float line::slope()’:
friend1.cpp:9: error: ‘int point::y’ is private
friend1.cpp:43: error: within this context
friend1.cpp:9: error: ‘int point::y’ is private
friend1.cpp:43: error: within this context
friend1.cpp:9: error: ‘int point::x’ is private
friend1.cpp:43: error: within this context
friend1.cpp:9: error: ‘int point::x’ is private
friend1.cpp:43: error: within this context
```

.3. Next I tried to separate out the point class in point.h and point.cpp and line class in line.h and line.cpp. But still here there is a dependency on each other.

Though this should be possible theoretically, I cannot figure it out how to get it working.

Looking out for answers.

Thanks,

Raj

**PS: This program is an effort to demonstrate the usage of friend functions alone**. Where friend functions are of two types, this is an effort to deal with the second of this kind:

1. Friend functions which are independent.
2. Friend functions which are members of another class.

So, usage of friend classes are ruled out in this case.

Comment: There's little point in making a member function of another class your friend. Just befriend the entire class: `friend class line;`.

Comment: Agree, but this example I needed to explain friend functions which are of two types: 1. Friend functions which are independent. 2. Friend functions which are members of another class. The above is the example for the second type.

Comment: The `friend class` declaration simply means that all member functions of the class are friends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `line` as a `friend`, not just a method:

```
 friend class line;
```

Other remarks:

- separate declarations from the implementations in header and implementation files.
- prefer full qualification over `using` directives (i.e. remove `using namespace std;` and use `std::cout` instead.
- prefer pass-by-reference for complex types - change `line(point,point);` to `line(const point&, const point&);`

**EDIT** For educational purposes - You can't declare that specific function as friend as the code is now because there's no full definition of the `line` class. Ergo, the following is the only approach:

```
class point;
class line
{
    point *p1,*p2;
public:
    line(point,point);
    float slope();
};

class point
{
    int x,y;
public:
    point(int,int);
    point();
    friend float line::slope();
};
```

You forward-declare `point` and change the `point` members in `line` to `point*` (because point isn't a complete type yet). In `point` you now have the full definition of the `line` class, so you can declare the method as friend.

EDIT 2: For this particular scenario, it's not possible using `point` objects inside `line` because you'd need the full type. But `line` would also have to be fully defined in order to declare its member as `friend`.

Comment: I needed this very program to explain the friend functions in particular. Friend classes are next topic, so I need to fix this for friend functions only.

Comment: @Raj there's some changes you need to make to the rest of the code (like replacing `.` with `->` where applicable). Also, this is just for educational purposes. In practice, you usually declare a full class as `friend`, and even that should be done seldom as it breaks encapsulation.

Comment: Yes agree that it breaks encapsulation, but as the author claims, there are some scenarios where it might be helpful. Like instead of making some instances public only for the reason that it has to be modified in only some scenarios and risking it being modified unnecessarily, friend function and classes would be helpful. But am unable to solve the above.

Comment: In general, there isnt a solution for this? How can it be possible? There has to be a way isnt it? I mean, apart from using the pointer approach which you mentioned. What if I needed the objects and not the pointers to those objects inside my line class for some reason?

Comment: Does anybody know what the benefits/drawbacks of the different types of friendship are? I've only ever seen friend classes in practice.

Comment: @Raj for these two classes, no. Because to declare a function as friend, the function needs to be declared first. For the function to be declared first, the class has to be defined. But you can't define `line` before `point` and still use `point` objects inside `line`.

Comment: Thanks, pointer way is the best approach. @Corporal - We should be refraining usage of friend classes and functions for the reason that it violates encapsulation in a way. But it is useful too in some scenarios as I mentioned in a comment above, where you dont have to demote a instance / method to public access coz of its limited access somewhere, and thereby risking it being modified from many other places. But yes, it is always good to know.

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out what friend functions are good for since you're so adamant about using them. It may be unwise to teach somebody about friend functions with a complicated example if they're not really useful anyway.

Comment: @CorporalTouchy - Yes I agree, this example was chosen coz we built upon the same line and point classes for small concepts. So, it is like incremental way of learning new concepts over the same old program. But yes, as in this case, it grows complex. And if we look at the positives of it, we get to understand more things like the usage of pointers, and what the errors were exactly and about forward declarations etc.

Answer (score 1):

Just make Line a friend of Point

```
class point
{
 friend class line;
 ...
};
```

There's very little purpose in declaring individual methods as friends.

Comment: I needed this very program to explain the friend functions in particular. Friend classes are next topic, so I need to fix this for friend functions only.

Answer (score 1):

Under normal circumstances, I would avoid using `friend` here at all.

Prefer to add a function to `point`:

```
float slope_to(const point& other)
{// Not checked, just translated from your implementation
    return ((float)other.y-y)/(other.x-x);
}
```

And implement:

```
float line::slope()
{
    return p1.slope_to(p2);
}
```

This way `line` doesn't care about `point`'s implementation and will not need to be changed when you implement 3D `points`.

---

Here is a demonstration of a `friend` of a *free function* (1.):

```
#include <iostream>

class point
{
    int x, y;
public:
    point(int, int);
    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const point& p);
};

std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const point& p)
{
    return os << '(' << p.x << ", " << p.y << ')';
}

point::point(int a, int b)
    :x(a)
    ,y(b)
{
}

int main()
{
    point obj(5, 10);
    std::cout << "\n point " << obj;
}
```

---

Here is an example building on your own code to have a `friend` of a *member function* (2.).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class point;

class line
{
    std::auto_ptr<point> p1, p2;
public:
    line(point&, point&);
    float slope();
};

class point
{
    int x, y;
public:
    point(int, int);
    friend float line::slope();
};

point::point(int a, int b)
    :x(a)
    ,y(b)
{
}

line::line(point& p1, point& p2)
    :p1(new point(p1))
    ,p2(new point(p2))
{
}

float line::slope()
{
    return ((float)p2->y - p1->y) / (p2->x - p1->x);
}

int main()
{
    point obj(5, 10);
    point obj1(4, 8);
    line obj3(obj, obj1);

    cout << "\n slope:" << obj3.slope();
}
```

In order to reference `point` from within `line`, I use (`auto_`) pointers and references, since the class is *declared* at that point but not *defined*. `line::slope()` is declared in time for me to reference it as a `friend` of `point`. This circular dependency is a terrible *code smell* and should be avoided.

Comment: My bad! The purpose of this program was to explain about friend functions. I should have mentioned it in my question. There are many round about ways to avoid it, but needed this for explanation purpose. Please see my addition to the question. Thanks.

Comment: You're trying to introduce a circular dependency between `point` and `line`. If you want to understand `friend`s, try an example without a circular dependency.

Comment: @Raj: I've updated my answer to demonstrate both of the types you mention.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a helper functor to calculate slope. This allows you to make the method of the functor a friend of the `point` without involving `line`.

```
class point;
class line;

struct slope {
    float operator () (const point &, const point &) const;
    float operator () (const line &) const;
};

class point {
    int x,y;
public:
    point(int a,int b) : x(a), y(b) {}
    point() {}
    friend float slope::operator ()(const point &, const point &) const;
};

class line {
    point p1,p2;
public:
    line(point a,point b) : p1(a), p2(b) {}
    float slope() { return ::slope()(*this); }
    friend float slope::operator ()(const line &) const;
};
```

With the implementations:

```
float slope::operator () (const point &p1, const point &p2) const {
    float s;
    s=((float)p2.y-p1.y)/(p2.x-p1.x);
    return s;
}

float slope::operator () (const line &l) const {
    return (*this)(l.p1, l.p2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you refer to the line class in `friend float line::slope();` before the class is defined.

just add the line `class line;` before the definition of the Point class

also change `friend float line::slope();` to `friend class line;`

Comment: I had done that, That was my point 2. But it is giving me errors. My post was not formatted for point 2 previously.