# Trying to resolve circular reference error between my deque class and tree class

Tags: c++, forward-declaration, cyclic-reference

Could anyone help me resolve the circular reference errors I'm getting here.

I've created my own `deque` class which is used by the `breadthFirst` method of `FibTree`.

Below are the highlights from the separate Header and CPP files. There are issues with *invalid use of incomplete type* and *forward declaration error* in `FibTree` files. I've marked these errors on the lines of code below.

**deque.h**

```
#ifndef DEQUE_H
#define DEQUE_H

#include "fibtree.h"

class dequeNode {
public:
    FibTree::Node* data;
};

class dequeList {
public:
    dequeNode* firstNode;
    dequeNode* lastNode;

    dequeList( void );

    void enque( FibTree::Node* );
    FibTree::Node* deque( void );
};

#endif
```

**fibtree.h**

```
#ifndef FIBTREE_H
#define FIBTREE_H

#include <iostream>

class dequeList; // ERROR: Forward declaration of 'struct dequeList' (2 ERRORS)

class FibTree {
public:
    class Node {
        ...
    };

    Node const* root; // 'root' pointer to constant Node

    FibTree (int);

    void breadthFirst(Node const* root);

};
#endif
```

**fibtree.cpp**

```
#include "fibtree.h"

void FibTree::breadthFirst(Node const* root) { // Breadth-first traversal
    dequeList* list = new dequeList(); //*** ERROR: Invalid use of incomplete type 'struct dequeList'
    list->enque(root);  //*** ERROR: Invalid use of incomplete type 'struct dequeList'
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

#include "deque.h"
#include "fibtree.h"

int main (int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    ...
```

I'd read on a similar post [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5543331/invalid-use-of-incomplete-type-struct-even-with-forward-declaration), that the complete declaration should be included, in my case of `dequeList`, so I added `#include "deque.h"` above the forward declaration `class deque.h"`, in **fibtree.h**; but this threw 16 compile errors to the `deque.h` class, such as these three errors: *'FibTree' has not been declared* against `FibTree::Node* data; in`class dequeNode {...`

Would anyone be able to highlight where I may be going wrong here?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the file fibtree.h seems to have a missing 
    #endif
at the end , and add #include "deque.h" at the beginning of fibtree.cpp and in deque.h change void enque( FibTree::Node* ); to void enque( const FibTree::Node* )

Comment: Thanks, I did also indeed have inconstancies with the `const` declaration. I felt I did have a circular dependency issue here, but thanks to all ( @JoachimPileborg @Oswald @Akobold ) for pointing out I didn't need to forward declare but just add `#include "deque.h"` to the `fibtree.h`. All working now :-)

Answer (score 1):

You must include `deque.h` in all source file where it's used. Otherwise you don't have the complete class definition.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of the `FibTree` class does not depend on the `dequeList` class. There is no need to forward declare `dequeList` in `fibtree.h`.

Only the defintion of `FibTree::breadthFirst` depends on `dequeList`. When you implement this method, the `FibTree` class is already known and you only need to `#include deque.h`.

Answer (score 1):

In `fitree.cpp` you are using your deque without including it's declaration. 
You should add `#include "deque.h"` in this file;

Also, `fibtree.h` should have a `#endif` in the end.