# Template specialization for a class which has multiple types

Tags: c++, templates

Class declaration is in a class.h file :

```
template <typename K, typename T>
class classx
{
  ...
  unsigned int func1(K key);
  ...
```

which includes this class.hpp :

```
template <typename K, typename T>
unsigned int classx<K,T>::func1(K key)
{
    return 1;
}


//Func1 for <int, typename T>       ????

template <>
template <typename T>
unsigned int classx<int,T>::func1<int, T>(int key)  // ERROR!
{
    return 1;
}
```

This results:

error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token

What is the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the second set of template parameters from your `func1` definition and the `template <>`:

```
template <typename T>
unsigned int classx<int,T>::func1(int key)
{
    return 1;
}
```

EDIT:

Additionally, [you cannot partially specialize a single function of a template class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/165153/52724). If you wish to do so, you will have to partially specialize the entire class.

Comment: Still does not compile : error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class classx<int, T>’

Comment: @vkx - "Invalid use of incomplete type" is commonly caused by attempting to use a class without including the header file (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5543331/invalid-use-of-incomplete-type-struct-even-with-forward-declaration). Simply forward declaring a class before using it isn't sufficient.

Comment: @vkx - Ah okay I see your point. Unfortunately you can't partially specialize a template function, [you have to partially specialize the entire class](http://stackoverflow.com/a/165153/52724).

Comment: Thank you.  If you edit your answer with this comment, I can accept

Comment: @vkx - Glad I could help!